# Is interface only for abstraction?

Tags: java, interface

What's the utility of interfaces other than abstraction and providing a workaround for multiple inheritance ?

If there is an Interface `I` having method `m1()` which is implemented by class `A` and another class `B` wants to access the method `m()`, what is the need of interface here.

Can we simply not implement that method in class `A`?   like -

```
public class A implements I {
  public void m1() {
  // business logic goes here
 }
}

public class B {
   A objectOfA = new A();
   objectOfA.m1;
}
```

Comment: That's not a _workaround_, that's a basic feature of OOP. Read some decent resource about, and you'll get a better grasp of it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a basic Object Oriented Programming problem. I suggest you to read [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). Interface help to **decouple** your design and implemention, make it easier to **reuse** code. Also recomand some materials about design patterns. **Head First Design Patterns** is a good start and not that hard.

Answer (score 2):

Put simply, an Interface is a contract. A good example is the `List` Interface.`ArrayList` and `LinkedList` implement the `List` Interface. We know that. You also know that `java.util.Collections` provides methods for interfaces, like sort().

[image]

The point is, this very code can be used to sort() either the `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`, because they implement the `List` interface, but you can also write your own code to implement more cooler things.This way,  people can use your code without having to ask you to support their classes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can simply implement that method in class A. But let be give a example of Interface so that you can understand your code. There is a concept of Re-usability in OOPs.

An interface defines a new secondary
datatype in Java.

An interface is a reference type only
its objects cannot be created.

An interface can inherit another interface
but cannot inherit any class.

A class cannot inherit any interface but 
it (a class) can implement zero to many
interfaces.
If a class implements interfaces then

1) It has to override all the abstract
methods of all the implemented interfaces.

2) Type compatibilty gets created between
the interface and the class. It allows an
interface reference can refer to object
of implementing class.
*/

```
interface Iface
{
  int x = 3;//final and public by default
  void f();//abstract and public by default
}

interface AnotherI extends Iface
{ 
  //more declarations possible here
}

class InterfaceDemo implements Iface
{
 public void f()
 {
   int i;
   for(i =0 ; i< x; i++)
     System.out.println("Interfaces are widely used");
 }

 public static void main(String args[])
 {
   Iface ref = new InterfaceDemo();
   ref.f();//allowed
   //ref.newMethodsOfClass();//not allowed
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A practical example

```
List<String> list;
list = thereIsMuchData ? new ArrayList<>() : new LinkedList<>();

public void f(List<String> strings) { ... }
```

List being an Interface, ArrayList and LinkedList implementing classes.

You can see the following:

- The implementation is your choice, based on technical knowledge. *In this java distinghuishes itself from simple languages where there is one-fit-all List.*
- Usage of list is not overspecific.
- The method `f` can handle *all* kind of lists.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @IdleMind. Also interface force you to implement all the method(s) containing the interface. You can say it is a contract to your concrete class(s) where you have implemented it.